# Need an easy solution to send Hex codes with a python IR(NEC) and RF(433.3kHz) library

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, ubuntu-18.04, arduino-esp8266, infrared

I want to transform my already working project from C++ into a python project. My project contains two components the IR-Transmitter and RF-Transmitter which are working with (https://github.com/crankyoldgit/IRremoteESP8266 and https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_AMRadio). 
So I already have all hexadecimal codes of my remotes which I want to imitate. Now I can't find an easy solution how to send these codes with a python library to the transmitter which are connected to the PINS. I want to run this code on my RaspberryPi3 which has the ubuntu server v18.04.2 OS installed.
Would be great if someone has a good and easy solution for this.

I tried to do this https://pypi.org/project/python-lirc/ but it is way more complicated than I thought and I don't want to enter all my remote buttons again. I searched about 5h and didn't find a working solution for me.

```
#include <RCSwitch.h>
#include <IRsend.h>
#include <IRremoteESP8266.h>

const int SEND_SAMSUNG_PIN = D5;
# ... some more IR sender
const int RESEIVER = D8;

IRsend irsendSamsung = IRsend(SEND_SAMSUNG_PIN);
RCSwitch rfSender = RCSwitch();
...

const char TYPE[][10] = {"SAMSUNG", "TEAC", "SWITCH", "LED"};

void initializePins() {
  irsendSamsung.begin();
  ...
  rfSender.enableTransmit(SEND_SWITCH_PIN);
}

# My Codes always look like 0x000000
void sendHexCode(const char* type, uint32_t code){
  if (strstr(type, TYPE[0]) != 0) {
    irsendSamsung.sendNEC(code, 32);
    Serial.println("SAMSUNG");
  }
  ...
  else if (strstr(type, TYPE[2]) != 0) {
    rfSender.send(code, 24);
    Serial.println("SWITCH");
  }
}
```

This is a small snippet of my c++ Arduino code which I want to transform

Comment: On thing to look into is embedding your python code in C++. There are some docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html).

Answer (score 0):

Python on the raspberry pi should have the `RPi.GPIO` library pre-installed. That gives you the ability to switch GPIO pins on and off, or to put out a pulse width modulated signal on a pin.

If you need to talk to the peripherals over I2C or SPI using Python, you will need to install additional libraries for that.

Ideally, you would need Python ports of the `RCSwitch` and `IRSend` libraries. If those don't exist, you'd have a couple of choices.

- Look at their code and "port" the funcionality that you need to Python.
- If the library has a C interface, try using the original libraries from Python using `ctypes`. (If it only provides a C++ interface you should not do this.)
- Write a Python wrapper for the C++ libraries using `boost.Python`.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, but I finally found a good Python lib for the IR-Transmitter. https://github.com/kentwait/ircodec